# GCC preparse and normalize whitespace for code generator

Tags: gcc, code-generation, normalization

I have a project that uses a scripted tool to process c header files to generate code (for marshaling) I know I can use the -E option in GCC to run the preprocesser, but I would also like to normalize/collapse the whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc) to reduce the complexity of the processing script. Is there a GCC option to do this.

Secondarily are there similar options for Visual C?

Comment: Remove all the white space characters?  That will end up in one big, massive line.  Besides, I wouldn't expect a compiler to do this work for programmers until it is mandated by the standards.  You might have to remove those white spaces yourself.

Comment: please note I said normalize, not remove. in some cases whitespace is significant (i.e. "int a = 2;" is not the same as "inta=2"). Also I would expect such a tool to remove comments since they are spcified to be syntacticly whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you run your preprocessed code through GNU `indent`? Will not give minimal size, but will certainly make it much more readable...